# Drools sequence of events

Tags: events, sequence, drools, accumulate

I would like to build the rule for following use case:
Accounts with multiple consecutive deposits (> 10) and immediately after the last deposit (maximum 4 hours later), extraction of the sum of the amount deposited.
For that, I have a Transaction class

```
public class Transaction
{
    private String Id_Event;
    private Date Date_Time;
    private String Id_Account;
    private String Operation_Type;
    private Double Amount;
}
```

I developed this rule, but it doesnt work with sequence events.

```
rule "Account"
  when
    $t1:Transaction($id:Id_Account,Operation_Type=="CREDIT")
    $t2:Transaction(Id_Account==$id,Operation_Type=="CREDIT",this after $t1)       

    not (Transaction(Id_Account==$id,Operation_Type=="CREDIT", this after $t1, this before $t2))
    not (Transaction(Id_Account==$id,Operation_Type=="CREDIT", this after $t2))
  then
        ......
end
```

I have the following sequence of events:

```
T1: A1, Operation_Type: CREDIT, Amount: 100
T2: A1, Operation_Type: CREDIT, Amount: 250
T3: A1, Operation_Type: CREDIT, Amount: 150
T4: A2, Operation_Type: CREDIT, Amount: 800
T5: A1, Operation_Type: CREDIT, Amount: 565
```

Where T are the transactions and C the accounts. The rule returns as the last, T5, when it should be T3 the last of the consecutive deposits.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You did not use the rule as shown to produce what you claim. First, `Transaccion` is not `Transaction`; second you cannot define the binding variable `$id` more than once. Thus, the rule cannot compile and execute. Please take more care not to waste our time.

Comment: Isn’t my intention to make you lost your time, I only have a doubt about how I ‘ll can built that rule. You are true, is Transaction instead of Transaccion, and the code exposed not completely shows the rule that I have to implement, because I’m developing it by parts, in this case that defined rule, should show the last transaction (T3) for the exposed sequence and however it doesn’t have doing, that is my doubt, my apologies if I don’t make me understood better. I already edited the rule written previously.